# Installed a water softener, but only getting soft water on the first floor

Tags: plumbing, water, water-softener

I live in a three-story townhome. I installed a salt-based water softener, but I only get super-cloudy and slippery water (with hardness reading zero) on the first floor. The first floor is pretty small and The bathroom sink is right on the other side of softener and water heater (the other side of the attached picture, basically).

On the second and third floor, I get clear water, but when I test the water with strip, the water is still on a hard side.

Is it normal and do I need to wait a few days in order for the treated water to go upstairs? This is what plumbing in my garage looks like:
[image]

The softener inlet is connected to the end of the second filter, and outlet is connected to “outlet” on the picture. I’m not sure what that mini tank-like thing is for.

Comment: The cloudy water becomes clear after about 30 seconds, but Imm wondering if the cloudyness will be temporary or it’s normal for salt-treated water. The water softener I installed is Aquasure Harmony series 48000 grain model.

Comment: The "mini-tank-like-thing" is an expansion tank for the water heater. You either need to await a full recharge (or manually initiate one) to prepare your softener resin bed for use, or you have some odd plumbing. Once you have flushed out the water in the pipes, what floor you are on should make no difference, unless the plumbing is odd. It should flush out in minutes, not days. But you do have to run water.

Comment: Take off all the aerators and open every spigot in the house for two hours.... Now how is it?

Comment: I have very hard city water going into a water softener and the water in the house is clear.